# How can Google make it possible to use ActionBar in Google Shopper app, which only requires a min SDK of 8?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm confused with this fact, and I think some feature must require

`getActionBar()`

and this function requires a min SDK of 11, but how can Google make those features possible?

I wonder Google may use ActionBarSherlock, is this just the reason?
But there is no mention of using it, but how can Google do this?

Thanks for your answering.

Comment: There is a sample called "Action Bar Compatibility" where according to the device operating system an action bar is provided. For versions bellow 11, the action bar is created from the resources provided by the application. It is a clean and easy to understand solution and it might help you get a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will take a look at those code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is actually working on `ActionBarCompat` . It's basically a `ActionBarSherlock` from Google. 

I suppose they are testing this in some apps already since they said at Google I/O that it is in an advanced state of development. I think they will release this in the next few months.

Answer (score 2):

> but how can Google make those features possible?

They made their own action bar, presumably.

> I wonder Google may use ActionBarSherlock, is this just the reason?

You are welcome to get a job with Google, attempt to join the Google Shopper team, and ask them.

> And have anyone ever use ActionBarSherlock on Android 2.2, plz tell me if it can make things just as well as ActionBar?

ActionBarSherlock definitely supports Android 2.2.